# Given a set of 193 elements, how many subsets of 129 elements containing a fix subset of 5 there exist?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set $N$ of $193$ elements, and fix a subset of $5$ elements $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\subset N$. I want to know how many subsets $Y$ of $129$ elements and containing the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ exist.

My attempt is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\frac{(193-5)!}{(129-5)!(193-5-(129-5))!}
\end{equation}

However, the number I obtain is very large, and makes me wonder whether my computation is correct. Therefore, **given a set of 193 elements, how many subsets of 129 elements containing a fix subset of 5 there exist?**

Comment: I don’t know why the math is not displaying correctly. I have tried everything that came to mind, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: it is displaying correctly though

Comment: Oh, it displays incorrectly on my device… And I don’t know why.

Comment: $(193-5-129-5)!$ should be $(193-5-(129-5))!$

Comment: Well,it would be very large. It’s 188 over 124. As we all know, 49 over 6 = number of possible lottery tickets is already a large number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, we can just remove the fixed subset of $5$ elements from existence, since we need to include it anyway, regardless.

So now, we need to find all possible subsets of $193-5=188$ elements that contains $129-5=124$ elements.

Then, it is simply $188$ choose $124$, or $188\choose124$.

Which is $$\frac{188!}{124!64!}$$